# trying to grasp Decorator design for dynamic hierarchical class relationship

Tags: c++, class, decorator, hierarchy

#### I'm trying to learn decorator design and I came up with something awesome, but I don't know if my idea will compile. So I created some classes:

this is the base class

```
class parameter
{
public:
    parameter(){}
    parameter(double mini, double maxi, double def) :
    mini(mini),
    maxi(maxi),
    def(def)
    {}
    double mini, maxi, def;
    double val;
    virtual double getValue() { return val; }
    virtual void setValue(double v) { val = v; }
};
```

This class stores smoothedParameters. `smoothedParameter` will add itself to the `SmootherManager` when they need to be smoothed and remove themselves when they are finished.

```
class SmootherManager
{
public:
    SmootherManager() {}
    juce::Array<smoothedParameter *> CurSmoothingList;
    void add(smoothedParameter * sp)
    {
        CurSmoothingList.addIfNotAlreadyThere(sp);
    }

    void remove(smoothedParameter * sp)
    {
        CurSmoothingList.removeFirstMatchingValue(sp);
    }

    void doSmoothing()
    {
        for (auto & sp : CurSmoothingList)
            sp->incValue();
    }
};
```

This class takes values over time and outputs a smoothed value.

```
    class smoothedParameter : public parameter
    {
    public:
        //smoothedParameter(){}
        smoothedParameter(double smoothingSpeed, SmootherManager & manager, parameter * p) :
            smoothingSpeed(smoothingSpeed),
            manager(manager),
            p(p)
        {}

        double smoothingSpeed;
        SmootherManager & manager;
        parameter * p;

        rosic::ExponentialSmoother smoother;

        double getValue()
        {
            return smoother.getCurrentValue();
        }
        void setValue(double v)
        {
            p->setValue(v);
            smoother.setTargetValue(p->getValue());
            if (!smoother.finishedSmoothing())
                manager.add(this);
        }
        void incValue()
        {
            smoother.getSample();
            if (smoother.finishedSmoothing())
                manager.remove(this);
        }
    };
```

This class takes a value and modifies it over time via a list of modifiers.

```
class modulatedParameter : public parameter
{
public:
    modulatedParameter(parameter * p) : p(p) {}
    juce::Array<modifier *> modulationInputs;
    parameter * p;
    double getValue()
    {
        double totalMod = 0;
        for (const auto & m : modulationInputs)
            totalMod += m->val;

        return totalMod * p->getValue();
    }
    void setValue(double v)
    {
        p->setValue(v);
    }
    void add(modifier * sp)
    {
        modulationInputs.addIfNotAlreadyThere(sp);
    }
    void remove(modifier * sp)
    {
        modulationInputs.removeFirstMatchingValue(sp);
    }
};
```

#### So here's how it works. You have a smoother and a modulator. If you construct a smoother inside the modulator, you get a smoothed modulator. If you construct a modulator inside a smoother, you get a non-smoothed modulator.

Here's how I wanted to use the classes:

```
// create the smoother manager
SmootherManager smManager;

// create modulatable parameter
auto mp = new modulatedParameter(new parameter(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

// create a smoothable parameter
auto sp = new smoothedParameter(0.01, smManager, new parameter(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

// create a modulatable parameter where its modifiers are smoothed
auto mp_sp = new modulatedParameter(new smoothedParameter(0.01, smManager, new parameter(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));

// create a parameter where values are smoothed, but the modulation is not
auto sp_mp = new smoothedParameter(0.01, smManager, modulatedParameter(new parameter(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
```

#### ok! here's problem.

```
modifier myMod;

// add a modifier to sp_mp, can't do it, sp_mp has no add function.
sp_mp->add(&myMod);
```

#### I'm trying to add a modulator to the modulatedParameter of smoothedParameter. I thought of a way, but this seems wrong.

```
auto mp = new modulatedParameter(sp_mp->p);
mp->add(&myMod)
sp_mp = new smoothedParameter(0.01, smManager, mp));
```

Any time I want to add/remove a modifier, I have to go through several steps. I could think of a way to remedy this but I am just so lost as to what is a practical approach because I don't know all the possibilities of C++. The point of decorator design is that objects can have a different set of functions. ...It seems like I'd need to have an "add/remove" function for every class, defeating the purpose of this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The point of decorator design is that objects can have a different set
>   of functions.

No, the point of decorator is to get the ability of flexibly extending the object`s base functionality, while preserving its core. Usually, the word "flexibly" presumes making this extension *at run-time* (dynamically).

Meanwhile, C++ is statically-typed language. It means that the type of an object/variable defines, what you **are** allowed to do to it and what you **are not**. `sp_mp->add(&myMod);` possible IIF **the type** (class) of the variable `sp_mp` has `add(...)` function. This decision is made at compile-time and no design pattern can change this fact, just bare with it. C++ compiler won't let you call functions/use member variables of the variable which are not part of its type.
 No matter what you do, the interface of existing type is defined statically. Wanna change it? Do it at compile-time.

Now, taking into account everything was said, we can make a logical conclusion: 
If you want to add some new functions to an existing type - create a new type.

Here is a more or less classic (I believe) Decorator implementation. 
*I did not used shared pointers just because... OP did not use them either :)

```
class ICore
{
public:
    virtual std::string Description() = 0;

    void Describe() {
        std::cout << "I am " << Description() << std::endl;
    }
};

class Core final : public ICore
{
public:
    std::string Description() override {
        return "Core";
    }
};

class IDecorator : public ICore
{
protected:
    ICore* core;

public:
    IDecorator(ICore* _core)
        : core{ _core }
    { }

    virtual ~IDecorator() {
        delete core;
    }
};

class Beautiful final : public IDecorator
{
public:
    Beautiful(ICore* _core)
        : IDecorator{ _core }
    { }

public:
    std::string Description() override {
        return "Beautiful " + core->Description();
    }
};

class Shiny final : public IDecorator
{
public:
    Shiny(ICore* _core)
        : IDecorator{ _core }
    { }

public:
    std::string Description() override {
        return "Shiny " + core->Description();
    }
};


int main()
{
    ICore* core = new Core;
    ICore* decorated_core = new Beautiful{ new Shiny{ core } };

    core->Describe();
    decorated_core->Describe();

    delete decorated_core;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I am Core
I am beautiful shiny Core
```

As you see, here Decorator did not change an interface (class prototype) - no new functions were added to the core. Also, it did not change any existing functionality. What it did, however, was the extension of the already existing behavior. It literally **decorated** the description of the `core` with *2 new word*. And note - this **decoration happened at runtime**. If we decided to change the decoration order from `new Beautiful{new Shiny{core}}` to `new Shiny{new Beautiful{core}}` the word order would change too (from `beautiful shiny Core` to `shiny beautiful Core`).

---

However, if you really-really want to fulfil your primary intent - adding a brand new function with decorator... There is a way, which lets you imitate such behavior. It would look ugly in C++14 so here is a C++17 code:

```
class Core
{
public:
    void CoreFunctional() {
        std::cout << "Core functional." << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Extend : public virtual T
{
public:
    Extend() = default;
    Extend(const T&) {  }

public:
    void ExtendedFunctional() {
        std::cout << "Extended functional." << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Utility : public virtual T
{
public:
    Utility() = default;
    Utility(const T&) {  }

public:
    void UtilityFunctional() {
        std::cout << "Utility functional." << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Core core;
    core.CoreFunctional();

    auto decorated_core = Utility{Extend{core}};
    decorated_core.CoreFunctional();
    decorated_core.ExtendedFunctional();
    decorated_core.UtilityFunctional();
}
```

The output is just as you would expect, but I am not really sure, if that may be considered to be a decorator...

Comment: I like the C++17 example. Two question. 1. Is `Extended{Utility{core}}` a different object? 2. If I wanted a vector of those, could I put `Extended{Utility{core}}` and `Utility{Extended{core}}` in the same vector?

Comment: 1. Yes, `Extended{Utility{core}}` is a different object. 2. I believe, only `std::vector<Core&>`, will work. :( That is why I called it "immitation"

Answer (score 1):

> The point of decorator design is that objects can have a different set of functions. ...It seems like I'd need to have an "add/remove" function for every class, defeating the purpose of this design.

No. Decorator pattern, as almost all the most known patterns, is all about interfaces and thus (in C++) virtual member functions.

You define your base class (either an abstract one or a concrete one you want to use as a base) where methods that can be decorated are virtual.
A decorator *decores* something that exists, it neither adds nor removes functions.
Whenever you define a decorator, you end up overriding those methods to enrich them and iteratively call the base class implementation of the same method. Then you pass around pointers/references to the base class and the user doesn't know if they are decorated or not. Just call it and the right thing will happen.

Let's consider this. If you add a new method, how could you invoke it from a reference or a pointer to the base class? You cannot, so you need the actual type, that is the derived one.
*This* defeats the purpose of the design, not the fact that you must add a method to a base class to be able to decorate it in a derived one.

If you are looking for a pattern that lets you add or remove functions from a class, consider mixins or whatever. That's not the goal of the decorator.